# MSBuild Targets - How to detect changes to .csproj content files

Tags: msbuild, incremental-build

What I'm trying to accomplish is detecting changes to projects during build so I can set a flag indicating that the project was changed. I've already figured out how to detect when a C# component has changed by utilizing incremental builds and CoreCompileDependsOn. But this doesn't seem to trigger when a content file of a project has changed. From what I understand, there would be a Copy task somewhere specifying SkipUnchangedFiles="true" depending on the setting of the content file within the project, Copy to Output Directory (Do not copy, Copy Always, Copy if Newer). I'm not entirely sure where this process happens, possibly the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file? Could someone please advise as to how I would add a dependent task that executes only if an updated file was copied to the bin output? A very simple example would suffice.

Comment: This might not be what you want, but could you not make it a git repo and run a script with a git command to see if there are any upstaged changes ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is in a company that uses TFS only. Also I can do the same thing in TFS but I don't want to use the VCS to identify the change because then some how I have to map the change back to the project so I can identify the product name. If I use MSBuild targets, then if anything in the project changes, I already have details about the project.

Comment: I can't help with that as my knowledge of MS build is not great, however my my other gut feeling would be to look at grunt or gulp .

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. This will write a text file with the name of the project ONLY if any content files that have 'Copy If Newer' set have been changed during a build:

```
      <Target Name="ContentFilesUpdated" AfterTargets="_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" Condition="'$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'False'">
    <WriteLinesToFile  
        File="@(ProductChangeFile)"  
        Lines="$(ProjectName)"  
        Overwrite="false"
        Encoding="Unicode" Condition="!Exists('@(ProductChangeFile)')"/>
```