# Xunit tests not recognizing when changes are made to the JSON test data files

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

I have a number of Xunit tests that serialize data from a JSON file to form the tests cases  that work just fine. There is a problem however when changes are made to the JSON file and these changes are not picked up when re-running the tests without rebuilding the project.

The JSON files are set up to copy to the build directory and everything works as expected when it is rebuilt but is there a way to have the new JSON recognized when I run the tests without having to manually rebuild before running them.

This can lead to misleading results and false positives and has knocked me into a cocked hat at various times so while obviously these discrepancies will always be caught later on it would be great to not have to worry about it.

This is the same on both Visual Studio and Jetbrains Rider.

Comment: have you tried to set "Copy Always " to *Copy to Output Directory* ?

Comment: “Changes are made”. Where did you make the changes? Xunit runs the test cases in the output directory (or a shadow copied location), not your source code directory, so unless the changes go to the JSON file in that directory (like rebuilding or similar), there is technically no way to go.

Comment: @eakgul Cheers but that doesn't appear to be the problem as the JSON is always successfully copied to a new build when changed but this isn't the case when the tests are ran without manually building.

Comment: @LexLi Essentially the behavior I want is to either be able to flag something to say rebuild this specific folder before running tests or to configure Xunit to recognise that there has been a change in the JSON in the test project and so to copy it to the output directory before running the tests (without having to rebuild manually).

Comment: Content files are usually outside of changed files, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552309/msbuild-targets-how-to-detect-changes-to-csproj-content-files So you might need some MSBuild trick to let VS or Rider automatically rebuild the project when JSON files change. Usually setting up a CI server with unit testing enabled would be a workaround, as CI builds clearly won't lie.

Comment: @LexLi I'm trying to make sure this doesn't cause any issues before it would get to the point of being pushed to a CI server. Thanks for the advice and I'll look into doing something with MSBuild but there seems to be no obvious way to set the tests up how I was hoping - so that the project would be rebuilt (and as such the JSON would be copied) immediately before running the tests.

Answer (score 0):

In the csproj file add the following, make sure to replace your_json_file to the path of your json file.

```html
<ItemGroup>
   <EmbeddedResource Include="your_json_file" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```